# Link VSTS issues to wiki

Tags: azure-devops, jira, wiki, issue-tracking

It's possible to link wiki page to issues in VSTS using the "#" sign in description or comments. Is there a way of navigatating this link in the opposite direction from issue to wiki? 
I'm thinking of something like the "mentioned in" section in Jira issues that permitts to navigate related documentation from definition.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

VSTS has no issues but has [**work items**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/index) correspondingly.

And yes, you can link work item in wiki page. The format is `#work_item_ID`.

Such as below example, the format `#195` will link the work item PBI `p8`:

[image]

For the opposite (show the wiki page as the link in the work item), it's not available for Now. Since WIT link is mainly designed for linking relations which has effect for the work item. You can refer details about [WIT link Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/link-type-element-reference#link-types).

For your situation, it's necessary to show the wiki page in the work item links, you can post the idea in [VSTS user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services).

Comment: Thanks... it's fine for linking the work item list, but the main point about the question is "Is there a way of navigatating this link in the opposite direction from work items to linked wiki articles?"

Comment: What do you mean "opposite direction"? Do you need to link part field(s) of a work item in wiki page?

Comment: No, from a Work Item page see what are the wiki pages that contains link to it via an # sign.